# Is there an R function can match if False then replace it by NA and if true go the list and pick the first number and so on

Tags: r

I have a list of 10 logical outcomes, TRUE or FALSE. And another list that has numbers in it and the length of the two lists are different, but the first list the length is fixed.

```
> i=1

> v <- c(201640,201710,201720,201730,201740,201810,201820,201830,201840,201910)

>   dat <- c(201710,201720,201740,201810,201820,201840,201910)

>   dat1 <- c(0.000000,4.000000,4.000000,3.875000,3.900000,3.916667,3.875000)

>   H <- v %in% dat  

> H
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE       

>   result[i] <- H

>   result1[i] <- ifelse(H=="TRUE", dat1, NA)

> result1[i]
         X1
1        NA
2  4.000000
3  4.000000
4        NA
5  3.900000
6  3.916667
7  3.875000
8        NA
9  4.000000
10 4.000000
```

So, vector v fixed and dat and dat1 have the same lenght and could change based on which subject you choice out of the big data. So, NA means that the data for that year is not available. For example, you can see that v starts with 201640, but dat does not have that so it has been replaced by NA, which is assoicated with FALSE. Then the next one is 201710 which can be found in dat so it gives TRUE and pick the first number in dat1 and so on.

```
> i=1

> v <- c(201640,201710,201720,201730,201740,201810,201820,201830,201840,201910)

>   dat <- c(201710,201720,201740,201810,201820,201840,201910)

>   dat1 <- c(0.000000,4.000000,4.000000,3.875000,3.900000,3.916667,3.875000)

>   H <- v %in% dat 


> H
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE        

> result[i] <- H

> result1[i] <- ifelse(H=="TRUE", dat1, NA)


> result1[i]
         X1
1        NA
2  0.000000
3  4.000000
4        NA
5  4.000000
6  3.875000
7  3.900000
8        NA
9  3.916667
10 3.875000
```

Comment: Not an answer, but `ifelse(H=="TRUE")` should be `ifelse(H == TRUE)`, or even just `ifelse(H)`. `H` is logical and you're comparing it to a string - it works because R automatically converts types when you compare them, but it could have unintended consequences. `ifelse(H)` works because `H` is *already* a logical - if you do `H == TRUE` you'll just get `H` again.

Comment: @Marius Thank you for that! You are correct, but it does not give me what I want. I am hoping to have something same as what I have towards the very end of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're basically looking for a left join; does that sound right?  Working with data frames instead of vectors makes this straightforward:

```
library(dplyr)
result = data.frame(year = v) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(year = dat, value = dat1),
            by = c("year"))
```

(`result$value` is the same as the desired vector `result1`.)

Answer (score 2):

I think `left_join` (also look at `merge` from base R) suggested by @A.S.K is the best way to structure your data. Anyways, in case you want to stick with vectors, here's an option using `match` from base R -

```
dat1[match(v, dat)]

[1] NA 0.000000 4.000000 NA 4.000000 3.875000 3.900000 NA 3.916667 3.875000
```

Data -

```
v <- c(201640,201710,201720,201730,201740,201810,201820,201830,201840,201910)

dat <- c(201710,201720,201740,201810,201820,201840,201910)

dat1 <- c(0.000000,4.000000,4.000000,3.875000,3.900000,3.916667,3.875000)
```